# converting elements in column to single text in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

Assuming there are blank columns in between and there can be more than 1 blank column in between,
how do I go about coding in vba excel.

Items in a column:

```
Nice
to
meet
you.
```

As a result I am looking for:

```
Nice to meet you.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Btw, I've written a function a while ago, I'll post it as answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, this is a function I've written to connect Range values in one go.
It concatenates it based on how you see it in the cell.
I'm not entirely sure though if I've covered all the possibilities but you can give it a try.

```
Public Function CONCATPLUS(ref_value As Range, Optional delimiter As Variant) As String
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim refFormat As String, myvalue As String

    If ref_value.Cells.Count = 1 Then CONCATPLUS = CVErr(xlErrNA): Exit Function
    If IsMissing(delimiter) Then delimiter = " "

    For Each cel In ref_value
        refFormat = cel.NumberFormat
        Select Case TypeName(cel.Value)
        Case "Empty": myvalue = vbNullString
        Case "Date": myvalue = Format(cel, refFormat)
        Case "Double"
            If refFormat <> "General" Then
                myvalue = Format(cel, refFormat)
            Else
                myvalue = cel
            End If
        Case "Error"
            Select Case True
            Case cel = CVErr(xlErrDiv0): myvalue = "#DIV/0!"
            Case cel = CVErr(xlErrNA): myvalue = "#N/A"
            Case cel = CVErr(xlErrName): myvalue = "#NAME?"
            Case cel = CVErr(xlErrNull): myvalue = "#NULL!"
            Case cel = CVErr(xlErrNum): myvalue = "#NUM!"
            Case cel = CVErr(xlErrRef): myvalue = "#REF!"
            Case cel = CVErr(xlErrValue): myvalue = "#VALUE!"
            Case Else: myvalue = "#Error"
            End Select
        Case Else: myvalue = cel
        End Select

        If Len(myvalue) <> 0 Then
            If CONCATPLUS = "" Then
                CONCATPLUS = myvalue
            Else
                CONCATPLUS = CONCATPLUS & delimiter & myvalue
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```